# DatePicker Dialog with Custom buttons

Tags: java, android, datepicker, customization, datepickerdialog

I am trying to build a date picker dialog but I need to have these buttons added to the view like below, but I cannot seem to find any resources to help. Any ideas? [image]

Comment: What buttons are you referring to? Also, edit the question to include the progress you have made to resolve the issue. By _building a date picker dialog_, do you mean building a library yourself or using classes such as `AlertDialogBuilder`?

Comment: I am referring to the buttons at the top. "Today" "Yesterday" "Last Month". It's supposed to be part of the DatePicker dialog

Comment: You can design a **custom view** which looks similar to this and call `setView()` method in a `AlertDialogBuilder` class to create your custom `DatePickerDialog`.